# Need help creating a generic way to do `base.extend`

Tags: svelte, typescript-generics, playwright

## Context

Hi all!
I am using [Playwright to test my Svelte components](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-components) in a SvelteKit project.

In every test file, I want to create two [fixtures](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures#creating-a-fixture) to make my tests easier to read and write:

- `component`: similar to the `page` fixture, it would contain my mounted component
- `pom`: a Page Object Model that would help my handle this component.
  I am looking for a way to create them with in a generic way so that I can use it in all my tests without having to duplicate the code.

## Example

As an example, here is a `FormInput` component I would like to test:

```html
<!-- form-input.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    export let label = ''
    export let value = ''
    export let type = 'text'
</script>

<div class="mb-4">
    <label class="label">
        <span>{label}</span>
        <input class="input" bind:value {...{ type }} />
    </label>
</div>
```

For this component, I would write a page object model looking like this:

```js
// form-input.comp.pom.ts
import type { Locator } from '@playwright/test'
import type { MountResult } from './mount-result.type'
export class FormInputPOM {
    public readonly textbox: Locator

    constructor(public readonly component: MountResult) {
        this.textbox = this.component.getByRole('textbox')
    }
}
```

For the sake of exhaustivity, here is the file exporting the `MountResult` type (following [the workaround proposed](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/27509#issuecomment-1754697572) in this feature I requested):

```js
// mount-result.type
import type { test } from '@playwright/experimental-ct-svelte'
export type MountResult = Awaited<ReturnType<Parameters<Parameters<typeof test>[1]>[0]['mount']>>
```

Then, I want to use it in my tests like this (simple examples to illustrate):

```js
// form-input.comp.spec.ts
test('displays a textbox', async ({ pom: { textbox } }) => {
    await expect(textbox).toBeVisible()
})
test('looks as expected', async ({ component }) => {
    await expect(component).toHaveScreenshot()
})
```

Of course, for this to work, I need to have my two fixtures existing. I can create them like this at the begining of my test file

```js
// form-input.comp.spec.ts
import { test as base, expect } from '@playwright/experimental-ct-svelte'
import type { MountResult } from './mount-result.type'
import { FormInputPOM } from './form-input.comp.pom'
import FormInput from './form-input.svelte'

type ComponentFixture = {
    component: MountResult
    pom: FormInputPOM
}

const test = base.extend<ComponentFixture>({
    // Extend basic test by providing a "component" fixture.
    component: async ({ mount }, use) => {
        const mounted = await mount(FormInput)
        await use(mounted)
    },
    pom: async ({ component }, use) => {
        const pom = new FormInputPOM(component)
        await use(pom)
    }
})
```

## Problem

As you can imagine, this block will be present in many (nearly all) my test files (meaning one for each component/page I create). It is a lot of duplication, and room for errors. And what if I want to add an accessibility fixture for example (actually, I do have one :D): I would need to add it in every file! I think you already know that duplication should be avoided when possible ;-)

So, I wanted to create a utility that would create this `test`. I was dreaming of something that I could call with something as simple as

```js
// Suggestion 1: this one is ideal, because we only give the "shape" of the objects (component and POM) and everything gets create automatically
const test = createTester<FormInput, FormInputPOM>
// Suggestion 2: this one is an acceptable tradeoff which implies that the POM constructor does not receive the component
const test = createTester<FormInput, new FormInputPOM()>
// Suggestion 3: this one assumes that I give methods that can mount the component (receiving the `mount` fixture) and create the POM (receiving the `component` fixture mounted just before)
const test = createTester<mount => mount(FormInput), component => new FormInputPOM(component)>
```

or anything else, if it is as easy as this.

## My (not working) attempt

To do this, I tried to convert my working specific fixture creation block into a generic one. It did not work (hence this long question ^^). I tried many things, and at some point Playwright is complaining about `FormInput` not being defined, or something else.
Here is my final attempt at making this work:

```js
// create-tester-fixtures.util.ts
import { test as base } from '@playwright/experimental-ct-svelte'
import type { MountResult } from './mount-result.type'
import type { SvelteComponent } from 'svelte'

type ComponentFixture<POM> = {
    component: MountResult
    pom: POM
}
/**
 * Create a new `test` object that extends the one from Playwright Component Testing, with the added following fixtures:
 * - `component`: the mounted component to test
 * - `pom`: a Page Object Model created to manipulate this component. Exists only if `pomClassToUse` is provided.
 * @param componentToMount The component to mount, as retrieved from a simple `import Component from 'component.svelte'`.
 * @param pomClassToUse Type of the Page Object Model to use. If not specified, then the fixture `pom` is not available.
 * @returns A new `test` object that can be used to issue Playwright tests, with new fixtures (`component`, `pom` and `makeAxeBuilder`).
 */
export function createTester<POM = void>(
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    componentToMount: new (...args: any[]) => SvelteComponent,
    pomClassToUse?: new (mountResult: MountResult) => POM
) {
    return base.extend<ComponentFixture<POM>>({
        component: async ({ mount }, use) => {
            const component = await mount(componentToMount)
            await use(component)
        },
        pom: async ({ component }, use) => {
            if (!pomClassToUse) {
                return
            }
            const pom = new pomClassToUse(component)
            await use(pom)
        }
    })
}

export { expect } from '@playwright/experimental-ct-svelte'
```

and I use it this way:

```js
// form-input.comp.spec.ts
import { createTester, expect } from './create-tester-fixtures.util'
import { FormInputPOM } from './form-input.comp.pom'
import FormInput from './form-input.svelte'
const test = createTester<FormInputPOM>(FormInput, FormInputPOM)
test('displays a textbox', async ({ pom: { textbox } }) => {
    await expect(textbox).toBeVisible()
})
```

which gives me this error:

```bash
ReferenceError: FormInput is not defined

   at src\lib\components\form-input\form-input.comp.spec.ts:49

  47 | import { FormInputPOM } from './form-input.comp.pom'
  48 | import FormInput from './form-input.svelte'
> 49 | const test = createTester<FormInputPOM>(FormInput, FormInputPOM)
     |                                         ^
  50 |
  51 | test.use({ viewport: { width: 200, height: 100 } })
  52 |
```

Do anyone has any idea on what's happening or how to make this work? Thanks a lot!!!